# Updating an object after a callback returns

Tags: typescript, callback, rxjs, jhipster

I have an Angular `@Component` which manages a Leaflet `Map` object. The `Map` is initialised in the `ngOnInit()` method. Later on in this same method, I try to retrieve the current `Membership` object from the server and store it in a variable declared at the start of the class...:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'aaa',
    templateUrl: './aaa.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    membership: MembershipGreenline;
    map: L.Map;
```

...then pan the `Map` to the `Membership`'s latitude and longitude:

```
    this.membership = this.membershipService.findCurrent().subscribe((responseWrapper: ResponseWrapper) => {
        return responseWrapper.json;
    },
        (responseWrapper: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(responseWrapper.json())
    ).add(() => {
        this.map.panTo(new L.LatLng(this.membership.latitude, this.membership.longitude));
    });
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
1 errors occurred during unsubscription:  1) TypeError: _this.membership is undefined
```

Removing the `add()` call removes the error message, making me assume that it is the attempt to build the `LatLng` object that is causing the problem.

The "Running first subscription" and "Done" messages appear in the log, so I know that there isn't an error in that part.

What I want to happen is run some code after `this.membership` has been assigned.

(I don't think this code is specific to JHipster, but that's what I used to generate my project)

## Edit

I have updated my code following @cartannt's comment:

```
    this.membershipService.findCurrent().subscribe((responseWrapper: ResponseWrapper) => {
        this.membership = responseWrapper.json;
        this.map.panTo(new L.LatLng(this.membership.latitude, this.membership.longitude));
    },
        (responseWrapper: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(responseWrapper.json())
    );
```

And am now getting `TypeError: _this.membership is undefined` on the call to `panTo`.

Comment: `subscribe` will return a [`Subscription`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html) - not a `MembershipGreenline`. The return value of the `next` handler is ignored; its invocation is (likely) asynchronous. You'd need to perform the assignment in the `next` handler.

Comment: @cartant yes you're right, I'm not sure why I wrote it like that. I have updated the code and am still getting an error (question updated) - it's starting to look like a question of scope.